# Changing user name and password in CouchDB _user database

Tags: passwords, couchdb

I am using jquery.couch.js to do signup/login/logout to a CouchDB _users database in my Sproutcore application. Is anyone aware of a method for changing user _id and password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in API to do this. The best thing for now is to read the jquery.couch.js code for account *creation* and use the same code or algorithms to do account *modification*.

Specifically, you need to update the `password_sha` and `salt` values to change a password. To change a user name, you must make a new document, then delete the old document. Just keep the `_id` and `name` values in sync and you'll be okay.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I suspected that creating a new user/deleting the old would be the way to go if there wasn't a modification api. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 24):

As far as I know the user id cannot be changed but the password can.

The [CouchDB documentation](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/security.html#password-changing) describes the process of changing a user password in detail, short:

- Get the `org.couchdb.user:<myuser>` document
- Add a password field with the plaintext password
- Store the document back to the `_users` database

As soon as the document is in the database, the CouchDB rehashes the plaintext password using PBKDF2 (at least since CouchDB 1.3).